# assets dir not found

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to add asset files to my android test project but somewhy assets from test dir are not available from inside test classes. What I am doing wrong?
The purpose is to have additional asset files for test cases.

Compilation is success from IDEA and command line, but test results are the same.

When I am trying to call getContext().getAssets().open("test.json") I have FileNotFoundException.

[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    debugCompile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    testBuildType "debug"

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know then sorry. Hope someone else can figure it.

Answer (score 0):

Created an [issure](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78592) in the android tools project. Looks like a bug.